# Check if request is AJAX in Python

Tags: python, ajax, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

Is there a way to check if a request is AJAX in Python?

The equivalent of PHP's `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'xmlhttprequest'`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If the AJAX framework sets the X-Requested-With header in its requests, then you will be able to use that header to detect AJAX calls. It's up to the client-side framework to do this.

Getting hold of the HTTP headers depends on your Python framework of choice. In Django, the `request` object has an [`is_ajax` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.is_ajax) you can use directly.

Comment: in Django you can simply do `request.is_ajax()`

Comment: Thanks @maraujop, that's much easier! I've updated my answer to match.

Comment: can't this header be spoofed?

Comment: This header can easily be spoofed, so use with caution. Also the `is_ajax()` method is deprecated as of Django version 3.1.

Comment: `is_ajax()` is deprecated in django 3.2 and forward as of 28th May, 2021.

Answer (score 4):

`is_ajax()` is deprecated since Django 3.1 (as of 28th May, 2021) as they stated that it depends on jQuery ways of sending request but since people use `fetch` method a lot to make call Ajax calls, it has become unreliable in many cases.

Usually, `text/html` is requested in the header in the first option in the browser when it just the loads the page. However, if you were making API call, then it would become `*/*` by default, if you attach `Accept: application/json` in the headers, then it become

```
application/json
```

So, you can check easily if the request is coming from ajax by this

```
import re # make sure to import this module at the top
```

in your function

```
requested_html = re.search(r'^text/html', request.META.get('HTTP_ACCEPT'))
if not requested_html:
    # ajax request it is
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [how to check if request is ajax in turbogears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187115/how-to-check-if-request-is-ajax-in-turbogears)

also this for how to do this in Django(it depends in your framework): [How to check contents of incoming HTTP header request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414687/how-to-check-contents-of-incoming-http-header-request)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone can find this useful, the [Sec-Fetch-Dest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Sec-Fetch-Dest) can hint if the request is an ajax call or not.

So one could have something like this:

```
is_ajax_call = all(
                    request.headers.get("Sec-Fetch-Dest", "")
                    not in secFetchDest for secFetchDest in ["document", "iframe"]
                )
```